# Positive square roots of inverse operators on different Sobolev spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces

Let $D$ be a self-adjoint (in the $H^0$-inner product) first-order differential operator on a manifold $M$, where $H^i$ stands for the $i$-th Sobolev space on $M$. Then $D$ extends to a bounded operator $H^{i+1}\rightarrow H^{i}$ for each $i\geq 0$, self-adjoint in the $i$-norm. To distinguish between norms, let us write $(D^2+1)_i$ for $D^2+1:H^{i+2}\rightarrow H^i$.

Then for each $i\geq 0$, $(D^2+1)_i$ has a bounded positive inverse

$$(D^2+1)_i^{-1}:H^i\rightarrow H^{i+2}.$$

Thus for every $i$ we get a unique positive square root $(D^2+1)_i^{-1/2}$, which is a bounded operator $H^i\rightarrow H^i$. The range of this square root can be shown to be $H^{i+1}$. I have a number of (related) questions about these operators.

**Question 0:** Is $(D^2+1)^{-1/2}_i$ a bounded operator $H^i\rightarrow H^{i+1}$?

**Question 1:** Do $(D^2+1)_i^{-1/2}$ and $(D^2+1)_j^{-1/2}$ for $i\neq j$ coincide on their common domain $H^{\text{max}\{i,j\}}$?

**Question 2:** Is the domain of the unique (unbounded) positive square root of $(D^2+1)_i$ equal to $H^{i+1}$? Let us call this square root $(D^2+1)_i^{1/2}.$

**Question 3:** Is $(D^2+1)_i^{-1/2}$ the inverse of $(D^2+1)_i^{1/2}$?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Question 0: Only if $D^2$ is hypoelliptic (of which the most important case is when $D$ is elliptic). Otherwise, the inverse "loses derivatives". Question 1: Yes. Question 2: Depends on what you want to allow for the range to be. If you are willing to live with distributions, then the domain can be much larger. Question 3: Yes, because everything commutes.

Comment: I suggest finding an introduction to pseudodifferential operators and studying it thoroughly.

Comment: Is D supposed to have real coefficients? Then there are not that many first order differential operators around which are self-adjoint.

Comment: Hi Deane, thanks for that. Do you happen to know of a reference for Questions 0 and 1? For Question 2, I'm intending for the range to be $H^i$.

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm thinking of complex coefficients.

Comment: Incidentally I don't really know of resources about functional analysis of pseudodifferential operators (I am told that pseudodifferential calculus does not always agree with functional calculus, though they may agree to first order), so any suggestions on this front would be great.

Comment: Also, how do you conclude D is self-adjoint in the $H^i$ norm?

Comment: I'm treating $H^i$ as the domain of the self-adjoint closure of $D^i$, with inner product $\langle x,y\rangle_i = \langle x,y\rangle_0 + \langle Dx,Dy\rangle_0 + ... + \langle D^i x,D^i y\rangle$.

Comment: I was thinking implicitly of $D$ as a first order matrix differential operator. A good book on pseudodifferential operators is the one by Michael Taylor. There is also the first volume of the books by Francois Treves. The one I liked best (when I studied this many years ago) is the one by Chazarain and Piriou.

Comment: @ougoah: If, for instance, $M$ is $R^2$, and $D=i\partial_x$, then the domain of $D$ is not $H^1$.

Comment: @Deane: thank you for that. One query I had about Taylor's chapter 12 he studies functional calculus of pseudodifferential operators when the manifold is compact, but do the results hold in the non-compact setting also (without bounded geometry)? Another point I am unclear on is whether a pseudodifferential operator of order $m$ on a general non-compact manifold is continuous $H^s\rightarrow H^{s-m}$...